# Auto adjust the height of div by content

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML page that contains

```
<div id="logo"></div>
<div id="content">
    <div id="transparncy"></div>
    <div id="contentdata">
        <div id="left">Contents  </div>
        <div id="right">Contents </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">Footer</footer>
```

and the CSS

```
#content {
margin-left:10%;
margin-top:20px;
width:80%;
position:relative;  
color:#37475e;
}

#content #transparncy {
opacity:.4;
filter:alpha(opacity=40);  
-moz-opacity:0.4;   
background-color:#fff;  
width:100%;  
min-height:430px; 
height:auto;
position:absolute;  
top:0px;  
left:0px;  
z-index:-1;
border-radius:5px;
overflow:hidden;
}

#contentdata {
position:relative;  
width:100%;
margin:2%;
padding:1%;
}

#left {
width:60%;
float:left;
}

#right {
float:right;
width:35%;
}

#footer {
position:absolute;
clear:both;
width:100%;
}
```

I have two problems,http://jsfiddle.net/wED4p/1/

- `height: auto` of the transparent div (`#transparency`) is not working
- `#footer` always gets placed over the `div#transperancy`

Comment: Can you add a jsfiddle?

Comment: What layout do you want because that looks a mess.

Comment: @Ruddy: actually i want transparent div' s height is automatically change

Comment: @SurjithSM: http://jsfiddle.net/wED4p/ but transparency is not work in this fiddle

Comment: It works fine... there's nothing in the `div`. Therefore it has no height. Also the footer is fine.

Comment: Why are using position attribute again and again, you have no need of that here. 

You have specified height:auto;, that means height will work according to the content of its inner div, but you have not any. 

Your code looks messy and also try to write clean css, avoid using unnecessary attributes.

Comment: @Ruddy: http://jsfiddle.net/wED4p/1/ please look this fiddle

Comment: @Parvathiiiii Yes and again there is **nothing** inside the div. So it has a height of 0px.

Comment: @Parvathi : check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/wED4p/4/

Comment: did you checked this above fiddle?

Answer (score 1):

[Your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kurbhatt/wED4p/2/).

I have edited some code in css just check it once.

```
#footer {
position:relative;
clear:both;
width:100%;
overflow:auto;
}
```

[update 1 fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kurbhatt/wED4p/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is your modified fiddle,

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Kk2sA/1/)

```
#contentdata {
    width:90%;
    margin:10px;
    padding:1%;
    position: relative;
}

#transparncy {
    opacity: 0.4;
    filter:alpha(opacity=40);  
    -moz-opacity:0.4;
    background-color:blue;  
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: Do you have any content inside transparancy div ??

Comment: No, i have lots of content in #contentdata, transparency div is for giving a transparent bacground, but when more content is added the transparent div's height remain same

Comment: Ok, i have edited my fiddle. Please have a look. I think you have got your requirement.